# Matlab: Writing avi file

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I am having a problem when creating an avi file using Matlab. My aim is to use an edge filter on an entire video and save the file as an avi. The filter works fine, my problem is the writing of the avi file.

My code:

```
vidFile = VideoReader('video.avi');
edgeMov = avifile('edges','fps',30);

for i = 1:vidFile.numberofframes
  frameI = read(vidFile,i);
  frameIgray = rgb2gray(frameI);
  edgeI = edge(frameIgray,'canny',0.6);
  edgeIuint8 = im2uint8(edgeI);
  edgeIuint8(:,:,2) = edgeIuint8(:,:,1);
  edgeIuint8(:,:,3) = edgeIuint8(:,:,1);
  edgeMov = addframe(edgeMov,edgeIuint8);
end

edgeMov = close(edgeMov)
```

When the loop finishes and the avifile is closed, I go to play the video and it says "Windows Media Player encountered a problem while playing this file". I've also tried, without success, Media Player Classic and VLC which lead me to believe that the problem must be the file itself. Using GSpot I checked the file and it said that the AVI header is corrupt.

Retrying the loop again returned exactly the same problem. What's confusing me is when I run the loop for a smaller number of frames, 30 for example, the video writes fine and I can watch it. The size of the video I am trying to convert is in excess of 1000 frames so I don't know if size is a problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the size of the file that has been created?

Comment: @Richie Cotton Just under 4GB, which is a bit less than the original video.

Comment: @Richie Cotton: I think it was so large due to no compression being used. Using the codec as I commented below the file is only about 20MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the following to create AVI

```
edgeMov = avifile('video.avi','compression','Indeo5','fps',15,'quality',95);
```

Give it a try.

Comment: "Indeo codecs are not supported in this version of Windows. You must specify a different codec."
Can you recommend a different codec for Windows 7?

Comment: I've used it with Windows XP, maybe you simply need to install codecs: http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm

Comment: Possibly, I'll have a look and see if that works. I don't know why I need codecs for encoding larger numbers of frames though. Strange!

Comment: Installing the codecs unfortunately did not work, however using a different compression codec (Cinepak) worked perfectly.
edgeMov = avifile('edges', 'compression', 'Cinepak', 'fps', 30);